# React JS user enters value in the input field on button click to display the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am working on simple react js task, when user enters value in the text field on button click I want to see the value to be set.

I am pasting App.js code please ignore person.js I am not using it for my task.

Not sure when I click on button it is more setting the value I am sure I am missing something here.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
 this.state = 
 {

 };

 this.setValue = this.setValue.bind(this);

 }

 setValue = (event) =>
 {


  this.setState(
 {

   a:event.target.value
 }

    )
 }
render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button type="button" onClick={this.setValue}>Set value</button>
        <input type="text" value={this.changed}></input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The input is rerendering on each keystroke with the this.changed value; however, you are never setting the value. You need to add an onChange to the input and set the this.changed value. Better yet use component state, e.g. this.setState({ changed: value}); and access via this.state.changed.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks a lot for looking into this, 
<input type="text"  onChange={this.state.changed}></input>                                     
 this.setState(
 {


   changed: event.target.value

 }
 <h1>{this.state.changed}</h1>
still not working

Comment: it worked. thanks again.

Comment: @Rohan please do not forget to accept the answer which helped you the most. This way future visitors will find solution of a similar problem easier and the member who helped you will gain reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the input should have a value attribute, which is used to set the value, usually this comes from the state, and a onChange event handler which updates the state whenever the input is changed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    objects: [
      {coin: "bitcoin",price:6500},
      {coin: "saicoin",price:1},
      {coin: "vechain",price:4},
      {coin: "nano",price:3}
    ]
  };

  this.setValue = this.setValue.bind(this);

}

setValue = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    a:event.target.value
  });
}
render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
        <button type="button" onClick={this.setValue}>Set value</button>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.a} onChange={this.setValue}></input>
          <h1>{this.state.objects[0].coin} {this.state.objects[0].price}</h1>
          <h1>{this.state.objects[1].coin} {this.state.objects[1].price}</h1>
          <h1>{this.state.objects[2].coin} {this.state.objects[2].price}</h1>
          <h1>{this.state.objects[3].coin} {this.state.objects[3].price}</h1>
          <h1>{this.state.a}</h1>

        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

onChange event handler should be in input element to get the typed value and set to a state and pass the state as a value to input element.

You should do something like below.

```
  constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={
            value: “”
        }
   }

    setValue(event){
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        });
     }

       <input type="text" onChange={this.setValue} value={this.state.value}></input>
```

Comment: Thanks alot it is working but when I enter in the text field it is dynamically changing which I don't want I want to enter in the field and then when I click on the button I want to see the value. what should I do to make it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use a controlled input, which stores its value into a state on change. Than use the state's value on click - typically pass it up to parent via `onClick` function prop:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  }
  
  handleChange = ({ target: { value }}) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const { value } = this.state;
    const { onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(value);        
  }
  
  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <p>state: {`{ value: '${value}' }`}</p>
        <input value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Set value</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const handleChildClick = value => alert(`"${value}" has been set in App`);

ReactDOM.render(<App onClick={handleChildClick} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated! how do I set with button click?.

Comment: I completed my answer with button. Hope it helps.